# Ignoring strings in LINQ order by clause c#

Tags: c#, list, linq, rally

I have a collection of strings that are as follows:

```
"[Unfinished] Project task 1"
"Some other Piece of work to do"
"[Continued] [Unfinished] Project task 1"
"Project Task 2"
"Random other work to do"
"Project 4"
"[Continued] [Continued] Project task 1"
"[SPIKE] Investigate the foo"
```

What i want to do is order these strings alphabetically based on the strings, but ignoring the values in square brackets. So I want the end result to be:

```
"[SPIKE] Investigate the foo"
"Project 4"
"[Continued] [Continued] Project task 1"
"[Continued] [Unfinished] Project task 1"
"[Unfinished] Project task 1"
"Project Task 2"
"Random other work to do"
"Some other Piece of work to do"
```

Question:

how can this be achieved in LINQ, this is where I've got to:

```
collection.OrderBy(str => str)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a simple regex:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\[[^]]*\] *");
```

that searches text inside brackets (followed by optional spaces), you can:

```
var ordered = collection.OrderBy(str => rx.Replace(str, string.Empty));
```

That will order by the text with the text inside brackets removed.

Note that there is no "secondary ordering" here, so:

```
"[Continued] [Unfinished] Project task 1"
"[Continued] [Continued] Project task 1"
```

will remain in the same order as written (Unfinished, Continued) and won't be reversed.

If you want secondary ordering, then:

```
var ordered = collection
    .OrderBy(str => rx.Replace(str, string.Empty))
    .ThenBy(str => str);
```

using the whole string as secondary ordering could be ok. But then:

```
"[Continued] [Unfinished] project task 1"
"[Continued] project task 1"
```

will remain as written (lower case letters are *after* the *[]* in Unicode) while

```
"[Continued] [Unfinished] Project task 1"
"[Continued] Project task 1"
```

will become

```
"[Continued] Project task 1"
"[Continued] [Unfinished] Project task 1"
```

because upper case letters are before the *[]* in Unicode.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I needed. I will accept this answer once enough time has passed.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you should write a method that retrieves "the part of the string which isn't in brackets" (e.g. using regular expressions). Then you can use:

```
var ordered = collection.OrderBy(RemoveTextInBrackets);
```

Your `RemoveTextInBrackets` method *probably* only wants to remove things at the start of the string, and also the space following it.

Complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    private static readonly Regex TextInBrackets = new Regex(@"^(\[[^\]]*\] )*");

    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = new[]
        {
            "[Unfinished] Project task 1 bit",
            "Some other Piece of work to do",
            "[Continued] [Unfinished] Project task 1",
            "Project Task 2",
            "Random other work to do",
            "Project 4",
            "[Continued] [Continued] Project task 1",
            "[SPIKE] Investigate the foo",
        };

        var ordered = input.OrderBy(RemoveTextInBrackets);

        foreach (var item in ordered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    static string RemoveTextInBrackets(string input) =>
        TextInBrackets.Replace(input, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some combination of extension methods like the following:

```
inputList.OrderBy(x=> x.Contains("]")? x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("]")):x)
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B6aTl0)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the above suggestions here's my implementation.

```
    var newCollection =  collection.OrderBy((s) =>
     {
        if (s.Contains("]"))
        {
           string pattern = "\\[(.*?)\\] ";
           Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
           return rgx.Replace(s, "");
        }
        else
        {
           return s;
        }
     }).ToList();
  }
```